# How to loop through properties of an object defined with an interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, if I have an interface like this:

```
interface A {
    prop1:string;
    prop2:string;
}

var a:A = {
    prop1:"hello", 
    prop2:"world"
};
```

How can I loop through its properties in this fashion:

```
for(var prop in a) {
    console.log(a[prop]);
}
```

This would complain because the `A` interface doesn't allow to index strings.

How can I resolve it without adding a hacky things like `[prop:string]:string;`?

Thanks

Comment: Cast it to a key of A: `a[prop as keyof A]`.

Comment: @caTS This does work also but becomes pretty annoying if we have more than one place where we want to access a property as we would have to cast it for every occurence.

Comment: In a structural system type like TS, you typically need another approach - a bit more verbose, unfortunately. For example, by defining explicitly in an array the keys you want to iterate over. It also depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `prop` outside of the for-loop and asign a type to it as we cannot use type declarations inside of loop conditions.

```
interface A {
    prop1:string;
    prop2:string;
}

let a: A = {
    prop1:"hello", 
    prop2:"world"
};

let prop: keyof A;
for (prop in a) {
  console.log(a[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Reminder that this doesn't go over *only* the keys of `A` but everything. At runtime, you may get more keys than what you might expect: https://tsplay.dev/wj1e1W

Comment: Don't say I didn't warn you when you get bugs because `for-in` loops go through prototype chains but you annotated `prop` as only keys of `A` :p